# Automatically generate value for a column in database

Tags: database, oracle9i, generator

I've an existing table with 'creation time' column in one of the table.

I want the value of it to be generated automatically by the Oracle when the row gets inserted, instead of me populating in the application.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use defaults:

```
create table Tab (
   created date default sysdate,
...
```